# Which OAuth strategy to use to authenticate owned SPA and which for 3rd parties?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, single-page-application

**The case**: the System-K has many microservices. One of them is the OAuth microservice which provides access tokens for 3rd parties that will consume some data managed by others microservices of the System-K.
The System-K also have a frontend that is a SPA web application. This SPA also consumes the same data that 3rd parties do, but with the difference that this SPA will be able to query privileged data since is the owned Sysmte-k front-end.

**The question**: Which OAuth strategy to use for the SPA? or I should use another approach to handle authentication request made by the SPA and leaves the OAuth server just for 3rd parties?

*Under the hood*:
The web application is built with Angular 7+, this sends requests to an APIGateway which is a microservice, part of the Sysmte-k, then APIGateway routes such requests to the target microservice.
3rd parties OAuth request are sent also to APIGateway which routes to the OAuth microservice. All microservices are build in Node and written with TypeScript.

**Update 1**
I do not want users who authenticate in the SPA to see a screen saying "Do you allow the System-K to access your Sysmte-k profile?" since the SPA is the System-k client itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: - Which OAuth strategy to use for the SPA? or I should use
>   another approach to handle authentication request made by the SPA and
>   leaves the OAuth server just for 3rd parties?

Unless your SPA has a backend server (which means that your SPA is not really an SPA) you are limited to using `implicit` OAuth. Implicit OAuth runs in JavaScript in the browser.

For implicit OAuth I strongly recommend using a third party Identity Provider (Google, Auth0, Okta). Getting the security correct in your own code is very difficult.

If you can add a backend service to provide three-legged OAuth, your security will improve and you will have many more options. Again I recommend a third party Identity Provider.

Comment: What do you mean with "three-legged OAuth"?

PD: my SPA is an Angular application which its assets are served through node-express as web server.

Comment: Three-legged OAuth means that you have a public facing server that handles the authentication. Three means client, your server and the Identity Provider. This allows for more OAuth features such as offline access, refresh tokens, etc. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth.html

Comment: How the flow could be if I integrate a third party Identity provider?

Comment: why SPA with backend is not really a SPA?

Comment: Single Page Application (SPA) runs in the browser. In this case I am refrerring to SPA not interfacing with a webserver that is providing session state. If your SPA is interfacing with a webserver then you should consider 3-legged OAuth instead of implicit OAuth as security is better and you have more options.

Comment: Before I can answer what the OAuth Flow looks like you need to specify the Identity Provider and the type of OAuth. Do some studying on how to implement OAuth and then decide on your design. Use a third party Identity Provider. Implementing OAuth securely with your own custom software is VERY difficult.

Comment: The flow that I have in my mind is: my SPA will use Resource Owner Password Credentials strategy to get the access token from my OAuth server. 3rd parties will use other strategies like code or implicit for their applications to access the data of my microservices. If I integrate an Identity provider in my SPA something like the update 1 will happen. I don't want users leaves the SPA to approve access from a website of the identity provider.

Comment: That is not how OAuth works. You will either implement `implicit` or `explicit`. The user will leave your page to go to the Identity Provider's site. The user does not get to decide. Since you do not want to the user to leave the SPA, you have zero options to use OAuth.

Comment: It seems that I will have to abandon OAuth using for my SPA. I think then to build another microservice that provides an access token from the username and password, and keeps my OAuth server for 3rd parties.

Comment: Hi @walter_dl! Could you please tell me what did you used here. I'm also wondering with the same question.